# invalid window handle with error code : 80070578

Tags: vbscript

I have written below vb script to find an window and bring it to focus

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
'bring the window to front
'title must be exactly what you see in the titlebar of the window
oShell.AppActivate WScript.Arguments(0)
```

I am calling this vb script from java code :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c activeWindow.vbs mywindowname");
```

Now sometimes it is throwing this below exception :

[image]

This is happening randomly.

Comment: Pass a valid handle. You are passing a number not text.

Comment: I am passing "mywindowname" as an argument, also it is failing randomly, most cases it is working and able to find the window and bring it into focus.

Comment: The message says "invalid window handle" AppActivate takes a string of windowtitle or a number for window handle. Now passing invalid names/handles doesn't normally cause an error, just nothing happens.

Comment: Is there any way to catch this error? I know vb script doesn't have any try catch mechanism. But is there any way to swallow this error and do nothing?

Comment: VBScript has `On Error Resume Next`.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for AppActivate :
objShell.AppActivate strApplicationTitle

Below code is working directly by passing title name 
`Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.AppActivate "Calculator"`

Or Passing as argument "WScript.Arguments(0)". Save this code in VBS file

`Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.AppActivate WScript.Arguments(0)
WScript.Quit 0`

from cmd type `wscript Sample.vbs Calculator`

Code is  working smoothly and Calculator screen is activating .